# Cucumber+Maven+TestNG-->Even after build success the console ouptut displays as TestRun as 0

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng

I am trying to automatically generate TestRunners using Cucumber-jvm plugin and run those generated testRunners parallely using maven-surefire and TestNG.
When i run the command "mvn clean test" even though the console displays as BUILD SUCCESS there are no tests run.

Below is my POM.xml and testng file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="3">   <!-- how many scenarios we can execute at a time is mentioned bt data-provider-thread-count-->
    <test  name="ChromeTest" thread-count="5"  >
        <!--  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>-->
        <packages>
            <package name="target.generated-test-sources.cucumber"/>
        </packages>
    </test> <!-- Test -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->

______________________________________________________________________

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.parallel</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.parallel.testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateRunners</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Mandatory -->
                        <!-- comma separated list of package names to scan for glue code -->
                        <glue>java.stepdefinitions</glue>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
                        <featuresDirectory>C:\Users\mbethu\IdeaProjects\comparalleltestng\src\main\java\java\features</featuresDirectory>
                        <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
                        <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber</cucumberOutputDir>
                        <!-- comma separated list of output formats json,html,rerun.txt -->
                        <format>html</format>
                        <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
                        <strict>false</strict>
                        <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
                        <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                        <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property you can pass ANDed tags like "@tag1","@tag2" and ORed tags like "@tag1,@tag2,@tag3" -->
                       <!-- <tags></tags>-->
                        <!-- If set to true, only feature files containing the required tags shall be generated. -->
                        <filterFeaturesByTags>false</filterFeaturesByTags>
                        <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of default JUnit ones. -->
                        <useTestNG>true</useTestNG>
                        <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' -->
                        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                        <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
                        <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                        <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
                        <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
                        <!-- This is optional, required only if you want to specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a relative path) -->
                        <!--<customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>-->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<forkCount>5</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>-->

                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src\test\java\testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
               <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
               <testErrorIgnore>true</testErrorIgnore>
               <includes>
                   <include>src\test\java\testng.xml</include>
                   <!--<include>**/*IT.class</include>-->
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-testng -->
        <!--    <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
             <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
             <version>2.22.1</version>
         </dependency>-->

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>-->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
        <!--      <dependency>
               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
               <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
               <version>1.2.5</version>
               <type>pom</type>
           </dependency>-->

           <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What are you running after clean install? You need to call for a real test like Run-Excel...

Comment: After running mvn clean install i am running the command mvn clean test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an Exception when running tests in parallel using testng, mavensurefire plugin and cucumber jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798913/getting-an-exception-when-running-tests-in-parallel-using-testng-mavensurefire)