# Getting an Exception when running tests in parallel using testng, mavensurefire plugin and cucumber jvm

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

> I am trying to execute cucumber feature files in parallel by
>   automatically generating test runners using cucumber-jvm plugin and
>   running them parallel using maven-surefire plugin. When running the
>   command "mvn clean test" i am getting the below errors
>
> Below is my POM.xml, testng.xml file and testRunners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">   <!-- how many scenarios we can execute at a time is mentioned bt data-provider-thread-count-->
    <test name="ChromeTest" thread-count="5">
        <!--  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>-->
        <classes>
        <class name="Parallel02IT"/>
        <class name="Parallel01IT"/>
        </classes>

    </test> <!-- Test -->

  <!--  <test name="new">
        <packages>
            <package name="target.generated-test-sources.cucumber.*"/>
            <package name="target.test-classes.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>-->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

> Below is my POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.parallel</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.parallel.testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Mandatory -->
                            <!-- comma separated list of package names to scan for glue code -->
                            <glue>stepdefinitions</glue>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
                            <featuresDirectory>C:\Users\mbethu\IdeaProjects\comparalleltestng\src\main\input\features</featuresDirectory>
                            <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
                            <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber</cucumberOutputDir>
                            <!-- comma separated list of output formats json,html,rerun.txt -->
                            <format>html</format>
                            <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
                            <strict>false</strict>
                            <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
                            <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                            <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property you can pass ANDed tags like "@tag1","@tag2" and ORed tags like "@tag1,@tag2,@tag3" -->
                            <!-- <tags></tags>-->
                            <!-- If set to true, only feature files containing the required tags shall be generated. -->
                            <filterFeaturesByTags>false</filterFeaturesByTags>
                            <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of default JUnit ones. -->
                            <useTestNG>true</useTestNG>
                            <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' -->
                            <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                            <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
                            <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                            <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
                            <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
                            <!-- This is optional, required only if you want to specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a relative path) -->
                            <!--<customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>-->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<forkCount>5</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>-->

                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src\main\resources\testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>

                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                  <!--  <testErrorIgnore>true</testErrorIgnore>-->
                    <includes>
                        <include>src\test\java\testng.xml</include>
                        <!--<include>**/*IT.class</include>-->
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-testng -->
        <!--    <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
             <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
             <version>2.22.1</version>
         </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
        <!--      <dependency>
               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
               <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
               <version>1.2.5</version>
               <type>pom</type>
           </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
        <!--  <dependency>
              <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
              <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
              <version>2.12.2</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>


Below are automatically generated testRunners
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(strict = false,
features = {"C:/Users/mbethu/IdeaProjects/comparalleltestng/src/main/input/features/HomePage.feature"},
plugin = {"html:target/cucumber/1.html"},
monochrome = true,
tags = {},
glue = { "stepdefinitions" })
public class Parallel01IT extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO] [INFO] ------------------<
>   com.parallel:com.parallel.testng >------------------ [INFO] Building
>   com.parallel.testng 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   --------------------------------[ jar ]--------------------------------- [INFO] [INFO] ---
>   maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ com.parallel.testng ---
>   [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
>   (default-resources) @ com.parallel.testng --- [WARNING] Using platform
>   encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is
>   platform dependent! [INFO] Copying 1 resource [INFO] [INFO] ---
>   maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @
>   com.parallel.testng --- [INFO] No sources to compile [INFO] [INFO] ---
>   cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:2.1.0:generateRunners (generateRunners) @
>   com.parallel.testng --- [INFO] Adding
>   C:\Users\mbethu\IdeaProjects\comparalleltestng\target\generated-test-sources\cucumber
>   to test-compile source root [INFO] [INFO] ---
>   maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @
>   com.parallel.testng --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252
>   actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform
>   dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   C:\Users\mbethu\IdeaProjects\comparalleltestng\src\test\resources
>   [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile
>   (default-testCompile) @ com.parallel.testng --- [INFO] Changes
>   detected - recompiling the module! [WARNING] File encoding has not
>   been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform
>   dependent! [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to
>   C:\Users\mbethu\IdeaProjects\comparalleltestng\target\test-classes
>   [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @
>   com.parallel.testng --- [INFO] [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------- [INFO]  T E S T S [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Running TestSuite [Utils] [ERROR] [Error]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.scenarios(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:31)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
>           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
>           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
>           at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
>           at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
>           at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
>           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:924)
>           at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>           at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.scenarios(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:31)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
>           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
>           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
>           at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
>           at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
>           at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
>           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:924)
>           at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>           at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> [ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 4, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time
>   elapsed: 0.767 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite [ERROR]
>   setUpClass(Parallel01IT)  Time elapsed: 0.51 s  <<< FAILURE!
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Lcucumber/runtime/io/ResourceLoader;Lcucumber/runtime/ClassFinder;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Lcucumber/runtime/RuntimeOptions;)V
>
> [ERROR] setUpClass(Parallel02IT)  Time elapsed: 0.511 s  <<< FAILURE!
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Lcucumber/runtime/io/ResourceLoader;Lcucumber/runtime/ClassFinder;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Lcucumber/runtime/RuntimeOptions;)V
>
> [ERROR] tearDownClass(Parallel01IT)  Time elapsed: 0.766 s  <<<
>   FAILURE! java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> [ERROR] tearDownClass(Parallel02IT)  Time elapsed: 0.766 s  <<<
>   FAILURE! java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> [INFO] [INFO] Results: [INFO] [ERROR] Failures: [ERROR]
>   Parallel01IT>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass:16 » NoSuchMethod
>   cucumber... [ERROR]
>   Parallel01IT>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.tearDownClass:36 »
>   NullPointer [ERROR]
>   Parallel02IT>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass:16 » NoSuchMethod
>   cucumber... [ERROR]
>   Parallel02IT>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.tearDownClass:36 »
>   NullPointer [INFO] [ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 4, Errors: 0,
>   Skipped: 2 [INFO] [ERROR] There are test failures.
>
> Please refer to
>   C:\Users\mbethu\IdeaProjects\comparalleltestng\target\surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results. Please refer to dump files (if any
>   exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  5.143 s [INFO] Finished at:
>
> ### 2019-04-22T23:12:30+05:30 [INFO]

Answer (score 1):

On https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin you can find

> As of cucumber-jvm:4.0.0 parallel execution is supported natively by
>   cucumber. As such, upgrading to Cucumber 4.0.0 is recommended and this
>   plugin is no longer maintained.

Note that latest version is 4.3.0 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng/4.3.0 You have multiple different versions in your pom file - please unify. Generally your pom file is quite messy. All you need is probably:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

For parallel execution check https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/testng/README.md#parallel-execution

Comment: i have updated cucumber to latest version.I want to generate testRunners automatically, apart from cucumber-jvm-parallel plugin is there any other plugin to generate testRunners automatically.

Comment: May i know apart from cucumber jvm parallel plugin what else can i use to generate TestRunners automatically

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, I do what I describe above and run `mvn test`. Sorry

Comment: That's fine, Thank you .. @lojza